# Display static image in public folder (rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have some images in the public folder, I obtain the url `/public/link/to/image.jpg` in my controller. I want to display it in my view, so I passed the url to the view.

But how can I display it on the webpage?

I searched through the post, most of them related to photos stored in assets folder, 
whichi can be retrieved by `<%= image_tag image-url (filename) %>` in view.

So how could I display image in public folder in view?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I just tested this out in one of my applications, adding an image to the public folder, and was able to render it in view by using:

`<img src="/your_image_file_name.png">`

I've never done it through the public folder before, but if I had to guess I'd say you don't need the "/public" part of the file path.

If I understand the question, that should do it - hope to have helped.

Comment: My situation was a little more complicated and I needed to use the Rails image_tag rather than a normal HTML tag in my application, but removing the "/public" part of the file path worked for the image_tag also.

Answer (score 10):

You can also use Rails-way via `<%= image_tag("/path/to/file.jpg") %>`

For security reasons, `image_tag` can only look inside `/public`, so you don't have to specify `/public` in the path — it will get added automatically.

**Remark** - try always to store images in subfolders in `/public` as it (image_tag) will not work if you omit `/public` and simply pass the image filename to `image_tag`, like <%= image_tag("filename.jpg") %> <- in this case it will go search `/assets/images` folder.

**Solution in action:**

1. [image]
2. [image]

Answer (score 8):

**This still works all the way up to Rails 7.**

Say you have two images `asset_image.png` and `public_image.png` saved respectivley under `/app/assets/images` and the other under `/public`.

You never need to include /assets or /public in the file paths in your code.

**Images saved under /app/assets/images :**

```
img_tag('asset_image.png')  # <== No leading slash; Looks in assets
```

**Images saved directly under /public :**

```
img_tag('/public_image.png') # <== Has a leading slash; Looks in Public
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use:

```
<%= image_tag('/link/to/image.jpg') %>
```

if your image is in `public` dir, and link/to/ subdirs

If it is in root public folder:

```
<%= image_tag('/image.jpg') %>
```