# Paperclip throws "undefined method 'gsub' for File"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, gsub

For my app I start using paperclip gem. Almost everything was good. When I fill my table "Users" with images I follow https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#quick-start this link.
After that I create task for my db called "addpictures" where I use something like:

```
task addpicture: :environment do
  User.all.each do |user|
    user.update image: File.open(Dir.glob(File.join(Rails.root, "app", "assets", "images", "svg", "*")).sample)
  end
end
```

After I run it rails db:addpicture 1 to 1001 Users get the picutres which I can reach by User.first.image.url but some of them from 1002 to 1019 don't have picutre. Why? Could you explain me?

Second things is I try set up default picture for attachment like:

```
has_attached_file :image, :default_url => File.open(Dir.glob(File.join(Rails.root, "app", "assets", "images", "original", "*")).sample)
```

but it doesn't work, when I try get this picture by User.last.image.url I receive Error "no method gsub for File". I try find solution in the internet but there is nothing, helpful.

**Update:**

View:

```
<div id="welcome-board" class="welcome-board">
 <aside id="left-side-menu" class="left-side-menu">
  <%= render 'partials/side_menu' %>
 </aside>
<div id="dashboard" class="dashboard">
<input type="search" placeholder="Find mum" id="find-mum-search" class="find-mum-search">
<ul id="mums-list" class="mums-list">
<% @mums.each do |mum| %>
  <li>
  <%= image_tag mum.image.url, id: "profile", class: "profile" %>
   <div id="profile" class="profile">
     <h3><%= "#{truncate mum.name, :length => 16}" %></h3>
     <%= link_to "Profile |", show_profile_path(mum.id), id: "view-profile", class: "view-profile" %>
     <%= link_to "Comment", show_profile_path(mum.id) + "#comments", id: "comment-profile", class: "comment-profile" %>
     <p><%= mum.status.to_s.capitalize %></p>
   </div>
  </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 enum status: [:coffee, :shopping, :helpful]

 has_many :comments

 has_one :address

 accepts_nested_attributes_for :address

 has_attached_file :image, :default_url => '/images/missing.png'
 validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/

 validates :name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3 }
 validates_associated :address
 validates :password, confirmation: true, length: { in: 6..20 }
 validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: /\A.+@.+\z/}, uniqueness: true
end
```

Table:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string "name"
 t.string "email"
 t.string "password"
 t.datetime "created_at", null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
 t.integer "status"
 t.string "image_file_name"
 t.string "image_content_type"
 t.integer "image_file_size"
 t.datetime "image_updated_at"
 t.index ["id"], name: "index_users_on_id"
end
```

The problem is why my browser doesn't display image? Even if file exist in folder which model.image.url pointing.

Comment: Rails gives you `Rails.root.join`, so you can compress `File.join(Rails.root, "app", "assets", "images", "svg", "*")` to `Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "images", "svg", "*")`

Comment: yeah but that gives me error "undefined method `include?' for #<Pathname:0x007fa42c20e978>"

Comment: `File.open(Dir.glob(Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "images", "svg", "*").to_s).sample)` - `Dir.glob` wants a `String`, `Rails.root.join` returns a `Pathname`, but you can convert to a `String` with `to_s`

Answer (score 0):

When you open a `File` in Ruby it needs to be closed when you're done. You can do this by calling `#close` on the `File` object, or if you pass a block to `File.open` it will close automatically at the end of the block. I suggest you use block syntax and rewrite your task like this:

```
task addpicture: :environment do
  User.all.each do |user|
    File.open(Dir.glob(Rails.root.join('app/assets/images/svg/*').to_s).sample) do |file| 
      user.update image: file
    end
  end
end
```

This might actually solve your first problem. You had 1000+ open files, and it's possible to reach your limit of available file descriptors.

For your second problem, the `:default_url` option of `has_attached_file` is expecting a `String` argument, but the return value of `File.open` is a `File` object. When you call `User.last.image.url` `paperclip` has defined a `url` method for you that is trying to call `gsub` on the default value you gave it, hence the error `no method gsub for File`

The `default_url` should be one generic default applied to every record, but it looks like you're trying to get samples of actual files from your `assets` directory. Here's the example from the gem's quickstart guide:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
end
```

Following this example, if you put a default image at `./public/images/missing.png` and set `default_url: '/images/missing.png'` it should work.

Comment: Ok, I see my problem but now I have different issue, I passing correct url to my image/attachment and in "inspect" of developer tool I see correct path but image is not showing up, why?

Comment: By correct I mean path which exist in my folder tree. I adding now by default  something like: default_url File.join(Rails.root, "app", "assets", "images", "missing.png") and that works fine I mean I can read User.last.image.url but in broweser this picutre is not showing up.

Comment: a path in your app directory tree is not going to be a valid url. However anything within the `public` directory is. You will want a default image in your `public` directory. e.g. something that exists at `public/images/*.png` should be available at the url path `/images/*.png`. see this post for more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446989/display-static-image-in-public-folder-rails-4

Comment: i.e. put a default image at `/public/images/missing.png`, then `has_attached_file :image, default_url: '/images/missing.png'` should work

Comment: So I did everything exactly like you write, but still my image is missing in broweser, I mean is not displaying it.

Comment: please update your question then with the new problem and detailed code examples, or ask a new one. I think I've helped you with your original question, and it's very hard to help you figure out what's wrong without seeing more of your code. There could be issues with the code in your views or elsewhere

Comment: @noname I've tested these steps and they're working for me. if you post the code in your `User` model, views, and migration then I'm sure I or someone else will be happy to try to help