# Show image with Rails server URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imageview

I have an image in my rails source in rails_project/public/images/2019-12/image1.png

I want to show image by acessing URL like:

```
http://10.0.5.140:8888/applications/images/2019-12/image1.png 
(10.0.5.140 is my IP and 8888 is my rails port)
```

I tried some solution but I always received the error:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/applications/images/2019-12/image1.png"
```

Please give me some ideas to resolve my problem. Thanks!

Comment: try `http://10.0.5.140:8888/images/2019-12/image1.png`

Comment: @Tun it didn't work bro :) I think url must has 'applications'

Comment: What's your rails version? Did you modify any assets pipeline config? What is your rails environment?

Comment: you should also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446989/display-static-image-in-public-folder-rails-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use asset helper method `image_tag()`. You should surely read official guide's [Coding Links to Assets](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets).

```
<%= image_tag('/images/2019-12/image1.png') %>
```

should work for you.

Rails use [asset pipeline](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) and serve files from asset load paths (default to `app/assets`, `lib/assets`, `vendor/assets`)

In **development** files under those load path are served by app server.

In **production** files under those load path are pre-compiled into `/public/assets` and served by web server such as nginx.

The `image_tag` method with

- relative file path e.g. 'file.png' searches for `/public/assets/file.png`
- absolute file path e.g. '/images/file.png' searches for `/public/images/file.png`

Answer (score 0):

Since your image is in public folder. please try this

```
http://10.0.5.140:8888/images/2019-12/image1.png
```

To show static images of public folder you can also try this:

```
<img src="/images/2019-12/image1.png">
```

Comment: because of my requirement :)

Comment: please check my above edited comment. it might help you